# I could not get the values in the lookup field

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, lookup-filter

I got a Lookup field in my VF page and when i tried to look up for a group i could not found it in the search list.

```
<table>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left;width:100px!important;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;color: #4a4a56;padding-right: 2px;">
                      <apex:outputLabel value="Group" for="lookup"/>
                    </td>
                    <table>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!order.Group__c}" label="Group" id="grp"/>
                    </table>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

[image]

The functionality of this look up is this has a filter criteria.
Filter Criteria 
(Group: TypeEQUALSGROUP-PNET) AND (Group: Parent Account IDEQUALSOrder: Account Name ID)

it will shows the list of account with type as GROUP-PNET and with Parent Account ID.

Please provide your thoughts on this.

this is the controller to get the parentID and also I have rerendered the page.

```
public NewOrderController()
{
   Order order = new Order();
    order.Group__c = accts.ParentId;
    accts=[select Id,ParentId,type,AccountNumber from Account where type = 'GROUP-PNET' and Id =:accts.ParentId];
}
public pageReference grouplookup()
{
    accts = [select Id,ParentId,type,AccountNumber from Account where Id =:order.Group__c];
    return null;
}
```

Comment: GO to standard edit page of that object and see if you can view the records here and you have proper permissions.

Comment: @TusharSharma Iam the system admin and I have access to the field, And Iam able to get the value in the standard Edit page.

Comment: How did you select parentid here. Also rerender this after selecting parentid and type

Comment: @TusharSharma I have tried the above method to select the parent ID and type. Still I could not see anything showing up. Please advise if Iam making any mistake here